# Vaadin 10 Button redicted to URL

Tags: vaadin, vaadin10

On a click on a Button, I need to do some action and then redirect to an external url.

All example I find are for older Vaadin version, and doesn't work on Vaadin 10.

Can someone provide an example please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases I would recommend you to use the new [Anchor](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/11.0.0/com/vaadin/flow/component/html/Anchor.html) component in Vaadin 10+. Its purpose is to cover your use case, replace BrowserWindowOpener, etc.

If your use case is to redirect non-logged in users to external SSO login page, then I would do it differently. I would not do redirecting in logout button, but instead implement it in access control of the views using `BeforeEnterEvent`, you need to implement BeforeEnterObserver interface in the view and override `beforeEnter(..)` method as follows:

```
@Override
public void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent event) {
    if (VaadinSession.getCurrent().getAttribute("userLoggedIn") == null) {
        UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJavaScript("window.open(\"http://vaadin.com/\", \"_self\");");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am curious, what would be the best way to make such an anchor look like the usual button?

Comment: how do I execute my custom code on the click? And how do I make it look like a button ?

Comment: I managed to make the custom code working: "Anchor anch = new Anchor("https://xxxx/cas/logout", "Déconnexion");
 anch.getElement().addEventListener("click", e -> {
     System.out.println("CLICK !! " + e) ;
 });"

Comment: Still not what I asked, I need a Button look (with icon etc..) and doing it in java. I tried another approch: not display the anchor, and fireEvent from the Button, but it doesn't work... An example would be great here.

Comment: @Tyvain, thanks for additional info, I understand your use case better and added more advice accordingly.